# Gradle Sync failed: Premature end of Content-length delimited message body (Expected: 27633912;received : 12844960)

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I have installed Android Studio 3.1.4 and the Gradle (Version 4.4) is not synchronizing; it says:

> Gradle Sync failed: **Premature end of Content-length delimited message body** (Expected: 27633912;received : 12844960)

[image: Process Name]

[image: Errors]

[Build.Gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnYkA.png)

Comment: please post your project's `build.gradle`... the `buildscript` might lack repository `google()`.

Comment: I have updated the post. By the way buildscript have repository google()

Comment: it is very difficult to work with your screenshots, because one cannot copy there and it always switches the page, when clicking on them... the actual URL would be https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.1.4/builder-3.1.4.jar which translates to `maven {url 'https://maven.google.com'}` ...the order of `jcenter()` and `google()` might also play a role.

Comment: Then how it'll be easy to work if you are facing difficulty with screen shots? And by the way the file (builder-3.1.4.jar) it which it is trying to download, already exists. Why it is still trying to download ?

Comment: ever tried to copy & paste text from a screenshot? while it does not even show the full stack-trace, but only a small part of it. don't wonder if you'll get no answer alike that... once deleting the whole cache and letting it download again might help, eg. in case the jar is corrupted.

Comment: Okay, Let me delete the screen shots and copy/paste all the text  (It is a lot of text, hope it will not be a problem) so you can look through it. How to delete the whole cache?

Comment: you'd rather have to delete your local gradle cache, in the user's home directory... it might just fail to resume a broken download and/or you might have network issues or a full disk. if you say, "the file is there"; can't you just overwrite it with the one from the URL which I've posted above?

Comment: I had already over written that.

Comment: "invalidate caches and restart" might be to only valid approach, because it is not only the jars, but also their index ...the file itself might not help much, while the index is still outdated.

Comment: Can slow Internet speed also be a problem?

Comment: not necessarily "slow internet", but an unstable connection could be related.

Comment: Okay. I'll try to run it on a stable/better connection (and It will most probably solve the problem, in my opinion) . Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was happening because of "unstable" internet connection. I used a stable connection and gradle synchronized successfully.