# Flutter FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. Could not download builder.jar

Tags: flutter

I have a problem in Android Studio when trying to run the project, I get this error

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project
>   'android'.
>
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'. Could
>   not download builder.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.5.0) Could
>   not get resource
>   'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.5.0/builder-3.5.0.jar'.
>   Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected:
>   8174407; received: 4456416 Could not download bundletool.jar
>   (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.9.0) Could not get resource
>   'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/0.9.0/bundletool-0.9.0.jar'.
>   Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected:
>   5248142; received: 4456416
>
> Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with
>   --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 19m 23s Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug
>   failed with exit code 1

Comment: The error sounds like a temporary networking problem. Could you try again?

Comment: I have tried it atleast 5 times. trying it for last 5 days but still showing same error

Comment: OK. I am not familiar with Android development, but I doubt there is enough information here for readers to help you. Could you edit your question to include the file that specifies your project dependencies?

Comment: [Possible similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51980686/gradle-sync-failed-premature-end-of-content-length-delimited-message-body-expe) - one respondent says they are using a VPN. Are you using a VPN to connect to the internet?

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19614

Comment: I am doing it with my mobile hotspot

Comment: I have searched everywhere but not getting any solution. But at one place there was a sol where they were just overwriting a fcode in some gradle file. My only problem is that I dont know how to open a gradle file

Comment: If u know how to open a gradle file I can try that solution

Comment: Do you have another connection to hand? Mobile data plans can vary enormously in quality. Or if you are not using a VPN, try one - they are encrypted so if the mobile provider is interfering with the connection (e.g. for traffic shaping) then perhaps it can be made more reliable.

Comment: i dont have any other service right now

Comment: I always use my mobile hotspot

Comment: Maybe try [cleaning your project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28581211/how-to-project-clean-in-android-studio) so you can do a completely fresh compile.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Its a VPN issue. Please disconnect VPN and try, it worked for me.